# Axios get request from local server url from within React app

Tags: reactjs, express, url, get, axios

I have a Typescript Express server with an API route that also serves a Typescript React app on the domain root.
E.g.

- `https://myapp.test` returns the React Web App
- `https://myapp.test/api/message` returns some message string

Inside of the React app, I'm using `axios` to sent a GET request to the API route and obtain the message:

```
function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState("");
    useEffect( () => {
        ( async () => {
            const message = (await axios("http://localhost:8000/api/message")).data as string;
            setData(message);
        })();    
    }, []); 
  return (
      <div>Message is: {data}</div>
  );
}
```

Can I supply the request URL as one relative to the current URL? For example, something like `"/api/message"`. If not, how should I be configuring React so that it can reliably know the API url, regardless of where it is deployed (e.g. Heroku)?

Answer (score 1):

```
          const message = (await 
          axios(window.location.host+"/api/message")).data as string;
```